# Silverstripe Template Issue

Tags: templates, content-management-system, silverstripe

I'm getting to grips with the Silverstripe framework and I've come across a strange error.

Say for example I want to create a new 'membership' page. Within mysite/code I have set up a membership.php page as follows:

```
class Membership extends Page {

}

class Membership_Controller extends Page_Controller {

}
```

Then I have created a membership.ss file within my templates/layout folder with some test output. I then do a dev build and create a page in the CMS of type 'membership'. On the front end if I click the new page form the nav bar membership I don't see the test text so it seems that the template is not being read?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Alan.

Comment: Quick check, do you have `$Layout` in your `Page.ss` in the root template folder? And see @Zauberfisch answer below for debugging...

Comment: @colymba Yes I have the $layout in my page.ss

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem.

My .php was missing the following:

```
function getInfo() {
return $this->renderWith('Media');
}
```

ithout this the Media.ss file will not be used! Hopefully this will help other who might be getting to grips with SS!

Comment: -1 because this answer is completely unrelated to the question. Your question never stated that you want to render the current object with `Media.ss` nor that you wanted it done on an action. Please either update the answer to explain this or accept my answer, which does already include an example of `renderWith()`

Comment: @Alan - Is your class named `Media`? If so, you shouldn't have to call `renderWith()`. If not, your question doesn't describe this case correctly.

Answer (score 4):

There are several common pitfalls regarding templates:

- how flushing works has changed several times in the past versions.
  I will not explain the details here, as those are prossibly subject to change soon again.
  However there are 2 things in the current version (3.1) that is of relevance here:

  1. /dev/build does NOT flush at all
  2. /dev/build?flush=1 does ONLY flush manifest and config (NO templates)

  (dev build does not use the template, so there is no flushing the template performed)
  this means that you have do **do a ?flush=1 on a normal page**, **not just** on **dev/build**
- The Template file has to be named exactly like the class (I think its case sensitive)
- check that the template file is not overwritten by another template file in another location. (eg if you have moduleName/templates/Foo.ss and themes/simple/templates/Foo.ss than the template of the theme will overwrite the module template
- make sure the template is not empty (this causes an error in SilverStripe, at least in version 3.1)
- Actions on a Controller can overwrite template ussage. here some examples:

  ```
  // this will not use a template at all, it will just print "some string"
  public function index() { return "some string"; } 

  // this will not use a template at all, it will output an empty string
  public function index() { return; } 

  // this will use template named "Bar.ss"
  public function index() { return $this->renderWith(array('Bar')); }
  ```

---

SilverStripe also provides a debug option to see what templates are used.
you can active it by 2 ways:

1. set `source_file_comments` in your yml config:

   ```
   SSViewer:
     # display template filenames as comments in the html output
     source_file_comments: true
   ```
2. use the "[URL Variable Tools](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/urlvariabletools)": just add ?showtemplate=1 when viewing your website

when enabled, see the HTML source (CTRL+u in firefox) of the page
silverstripe will add  comments to let you know what templates are used.

Comment: @Zauberfisach - thank you for your reply. I've run some tests and created a page type with a ridiculous file name so as to avoid any conflicts, I then create the corresponding .ss file, no matter what I do I cannot get the template file to be read, I have down the rebuild and flush. I've set up a local test in order to try and replicate the issue, I've copied across the index.php, 2 x page.ss files and my newpage.php and newpage.ss files but CANNOT replicate the issue. Other than pulling my files acorss one by one and rebuilding not sure how to proceed.

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: No I'm still banging my head against the wall. I copied the entire site to my local server and the the problem disappears, identical files on dev server and I can't add the new template. This suggested to me that it was a file permissions error but I have checked everything and full permissions exist.

Comment: yeah, sounds like a problem with the tmp / cache folder. try creating a new folder called "silverstripe-cache" in your root web directory on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your class has a `Page_Controller` extension declared and named correctly. I recently had this issue. The page controller extension had a typo, so the template file was not being used.

So for example, if your page class is RidiculouslyNamedPage

```
class RidiculouslyNamedPage extends Page {

}

class RidiculouslyNamedPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

}
```

Then in your `themes/[theme-name]/templates/Layout/` folder you would have your `RidiculouslyNamedPage.ss`.

If you misspell `RidiculouslyNamedPage_Controller` the template will not get called.

Comment: Thanks I doubled checked everything and there are no typos. As mentioned above, if move the site to my local server the template is picked up, on my dev server problem is present!